# Jquery cycle - center divs

Tags: jquery, css, cycle

I am trying to keep `div`s with text that are on a cycle, centered within the parent element. This works fine when there is only one quote `div`. Once I have more than one and they are cycling, they appear left justified.

http://jsfiddle.net/k8UvP/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtRotate').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight',
        timeout: 3,
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i found some solutions for you :

- One change your styles and style your `a` tag directly:

  First you need to set the `width` to `100%` --- why i use `!important` because the plugin makes inline style with new `width` based on windows size only at begin, with this you can have center even resizing the window.

  ```
   #txtRotate {
     width: 100% !important;
   }
   .quoteRotate {
     width: 100% !important;
   }
  ```

  Second you set `width` and `margin` for your elements inside:

  ```
   .quoteRotate a, .quoteRotate .author {
     display:block;
     width:600px;
     margin:auto;
   }
  ```

  See the demo here **http://jsfiddle.net/k8UvP/25/**
- The second option i can propose is make use of this add-on i found http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/center.php.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to change the `scrollRight` effect like so, centering the child element using `left:50%` and a negative `margin-left` of half its width and changing the `left` position of `txtRotate`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtRotate').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight',
        timeout: 900,
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });
    $('.quoteRotate').css({'left':'50%', 'margin-left':'-300px'});
});

$.fn.cycle.transitions.scrollRight = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    $cont.css('overflow','hidden');
    opts.before.push($.fn.cycle.commonReset);
    var w = $cont.width();
    opts.cssFirst = { left: 0 };
    opts.cssBefore= { left: -w, top: 0 };
    opts.animIn   = { left: "50%" };
    opts.animOut  = { left: 2*w };
};
```

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/k8UvP/27/)

You might also want to use `text-align:center` on `quoteRotate` to center align the text

Comment: On a side note you should put a longer timeout, it's hard to read it all before it cycles

Comment: This isn't what he's asking. He wants the quotes centered aligned on the page. Try resizing the window and you'll see that the quote's containers are indeed right aligned in relation to the page.

Comment: Yes timeout is just temp for example.  Real site will have longer timeout.

Comment: @kei I updated my solution so that it solves the real question

Comment: @user1110562 On another side note try not to mix inline styles and a stylesheet if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/MPt73/

```
#txtRotate {
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: No I need the entire div (.quoteRotate) centered in the parent div.

Comment: `.quoteRotate {
    width: 600px;
    height: 160px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    vertical-align:middle;
}`
Added the last line "vertical-align:middle;" That's a way to align divs in the middle.

Comment: Try setting a px based width to the parent (#txtRotate) and setting the width of .quoteRotate on a percentage based one. Like this one : http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/c922a/1/ it does looking good from here.

Answer (score 0):

I've add some colors to identify.
Well I think using percentage in .quoteRotate is better.

```
.quoteRotate {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 160px;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: block;
}
```

Take a look at Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k8UvP/5/

Comment: Increase size of your window an you will see what happen

Comment: Yes it is not always centered depending on the size of browser.  It seems that jQuery cycle is overwriting some CSS when it is applied, but I do not know why or what.